# ng-options with simple array init

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid, ng-options

I'm a little bit confused with Angular and `ng-options`.

I have a simple array and I want to init a select with it. But, I want that options value = label.

#### script.js

```
$scope.options = ['var1', 'var2', 'var3'];
```

#### html

```
<select ng-model="myselect" ng-options="o for o in options"></select>
```

What I get:

```
<option value="0">var1</option>
<option value="1">var2</option>
<option value="2">var3</option>
```

What I want:

```
<option value="var1">var1</option>
<option value="var2">var2</option>
<option value="var3">var3</option>
```

So I tried:

```
<select ng-model="myselect2" ng-init=0 ng-options="options[k] as v for (k,v) in options"></select>

<select ng-model="myselect3" ng-init=0 ng-options="b as b for b in options"></select>
```

(But it didn’t work.)

#### Edit:

My form is submitted externally, which is why I need 'var1' as the value instead of 0.

Answer (score 313, accepted):

You actually had it correct in your third attempt.

```
 <select ng-model="myselect" ng-options="o as o for o in options"></select>
```

See a working example here:
http://plnkr.co/edit/xEERH2zDQ5mPXt9qCl6k?p=preview

The trick is that AngularJS writes the keys as numbers from 0 to n anyway, and translates back when updating the model.

As a result, the HTML will look incorrect but the model will still be set properly when choosing a value. *(i.e. AngularJS will translate '0' back to 'var1')*

The solution by Epokk also works, however if you're loading data asynchronously you might find it doesn't always update correctly. Using ngOptions will correctly refresh when the scope changes.

Comment: You're off topic. You didn't understand the instructions. He want `value` in his `select`.

Comment: I understood the instructions, however it's quite likely his intent is to bind the 'value' to the model, and is misunderstanding what's happening due to the way AngularJs is rendering the tag.

Comment: It works if you get select's value with angular, but in my case (ie classic submit form), values will be 0,1,2,3, not var1,var2,var3

Comment: I assumed you were binding to the model, but if you're simply using AngularJS to render a form submitted externally to angular, then use EpokK's solution.

Comment: Question was pretty clear, but I figured there was a good chance you were simply wanting to bind to the model, and looking at the rendered HTML assuming you were getting the ngOptions statement wrong, when you were in fact correct.

Comment: o for o in options is enough

Comment: Is it just me, or is this the most jacked-up and unclear syntax ever?

Comment: Not just you. It makes sense once you understand it, but it could be a lot nicer.

Comment: It does not work for me. I am getting 0, 1, 2, .. etc in the options text.

Comment: @JamesDavies thanks. your answer doesnt solve Dragus question, but solves mine. :)

Comment: is there any way to get the actual value instead of the index.

Comment: I don't like this solution because it does not preselect the options if you init `$scope.myselect = 0;`. You can init with `$scope.myselect = 'var1';` but e.g. if you reload from a database you have to map the value first.

Comment: So I would go for an array of json objects: http://plnkr.co/edit/Fie2LFbVwncN69RM1pPV?p=preview if data needs to be reloaded.

Answer (score 35):

You can use `ng-repeat` with `option` like this:

```
<form>
    <select ng-model="yourSelect" 
        ng-options="option as option for option in ['var1', 'var2', 'var3']"
        ng-init="yourSelect='var1'"></select>
    <input type="hidden" name="yourSelect" value="{{yourSelect}}" />
</form>
```

When you submit your `form` you can get value of input hidden.

---

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/35ZO1hKflwoaifebD501)**</kbd>

[ng-selected](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angSelected)
[ng-repeat](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angRepeat)

Comment: If you have dicreased my answer, check my new solution.

Answer (score 24):

If you setup your select like the following:

```
<select ng-model="myselect" ng-options="b for b in options track by b"></select>
```

you will get:

```
<option value="var1">var1</option>
<option value="var2">var2</option>
<option value="var3">var3</option>
```

working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/x8kCZ/15/

Comment: This solution was the only one that worked for me for selecting the initial value in an array of strings.

Comment: yeah this should be the answer, the track by does the magic for me.

Comment: i was least expecting after following above solutions but this was the easy way out

Answer (score 22):

you could use something like

```
<select ng-model="myselect">
    <option ng-repeat="o in options" ng-selected="{{o==myselect}}" value="{{o}}">
        {{o}}
    </option>
</select>
```

using ng-selected you preselect the option in case myselect was prefilled.

I prefer this method over ng-options anyway, as ng-options only works with arrays. ng-repeat also works with json-like objects.

Comment: `ng-options` works with object data sources, too. See https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select

Comment: Although others gave workarounds, this soltion is by far the most elegant and close to old html style, works with both angular model binding and form submital. Thanks!

Comment: ng-selected does not need the handlebars since it is an angular directive. Excellent solution.

Answer (score 10):

```
<select ng-model="option" ng-options="o for o in options">
```

$scope.option will be equal to 'var1' after change, even you see value="0" in generated html

[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/4dgLPKtFjtcT3MzOobq7?p=preview)