# How to get label=value using ng-options with simple array

Tags: angularjs

I have an array like `$scope.years = ['1900', '1901', '1902'];`

If I use `<select ng-model="chosenYear" ng-options="choice for choice in years"></select>`
I get

```
<option value="0">1900</option>
<option value="1">1901</option>
<option value="2">1902</option>
```

where index of the array becomes the '`value`' of options. How can I have both `value` and `label` equal (both being 1900, 1902, 1902, etc) ?

A [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18202106/ng-options-with-simple-array-init) question has an accepted answer, but it doesn't do this thing at all.

Angular version :  **1.2.16**

Comment: look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14552976/how-to-get-option-text-value-using-angularjs), is similar with your case

Comment: Just a quick question, given that you have a model (`chosenYear`) which is the selected item and you have a list of selectable items, why do you need to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want is `<select ng-model="chosenYear" ng-options="choice as choice for choice in years"></select>`

EDIT:
since above does not work in angular `1.2.16` try below

```
<select ng-model="chosenYear" ng-options="choice for choice in years track by choice"></select>
```

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.years = ['1900', '1901', '1902'];
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">


<select ng-model="chosenYear" ng-options="choice for choice in years track by choice"></select>
</div>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: yes, just checked. It is not working with your version, though working perfectly with `V 1.5.8`. I am not sure if `1.2.16` has support for this feature.

Comment: @Daud I have edited my answer and added a snippet for new code. Can you try this ?

Comment: I am not sure, since it works in this bare bone snippet I guess its due to some other part of your code.

Comment: Yes, it was my issue. Working now.

Answer (score 1):

look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14552976/how-to-get-option-text-value-using-angularjs), is similar with your case or you can just use ng-repeat and create value dynamically`<option ng-repeat="option in selecteOptions" value="option">{{option}}</option>`

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.years = [{
      label: "1900",
      value: "1900"
    }, {
      label: "1901",
      value: "1901"
    }, {
      label: "1902",
      value: "1902"
    },

  ];
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>

<body>

  <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

    <p>Select a year:</p>

   

    <select  name="mySelect" id="mySelect" ng-options="option.label for option in years track by option.value" ng-model="selectedCar"></select>

    <h1>You selected: {{selectedCar.label}}</h1>

  </div>



</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Since the original question asked for an 'ng-options' solution, please add that alternative too.

Comment: $digest is not a part of this snippet, as i am not getting any error in it, it's pretty working.

Comment: You are most welcom :)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using ng-repeat, use this instead:

`<select ng-model="selectedItem">
    <option ng-repeat="year in years" value="{{year}}">{{year}}</option>
 </select>`