# angular 1.5X [ngOptions] for regular array

Tags: angularjs, ng-options

I'm trying to create a drop down menu from a simple array in Angular using the ngOptions attribute from angular 1.5, however after reading the docs and browsing the web I can't seem to get it to work with a 'simple' array (with objects it works fine).

I got the following Data

```
 ["Interne Vacatures","Human Resources","Sales"]
```

I use the following code in my view

```
<select class="form-control" ng-model="widget.GroupNameSearch" id="widgetselectedGroupName" ng-options="group as widget.GroupNameSearch for group in widget.GroupNameSearch | orderBy:'GroupNameSearch' track by widget.GroupNameSearch">
   <option value="" disabled selected>--- Kies een group ---</option>
   <option value="" ng-if="false"></option>
</select>
```

However my html creates the following:
[image]

I am not sure why it produces these results but if i change my array to a json object I can get it to work. Unfortunetly I don't ant to waste the memory. Below is a working example with JSON:

```
{"groupName": {
    "groupName":"Group 100",
    "mail":"Group100@one365dev1.onmicrosoft.com"}
}



  <select class="form-control" ng-model="widget.selectedGroupName.groupName" id="widgetselectedGroupName" ng-options="group as group.groupName for group in widget.GroupNameSearch | orderBy:'groupName' track by group.groupName" >
                    <option value="" disabled selected>--- Kies een group ---</option>
                    <option value="" ng-if="false"></option> 
                </select>
```

Any help would be much appreciated.
Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because of `widget.GroupNameSearch` in your options.

```
ng-options="group as widget.GroupNameSearch for group in widget.GroupNameSearch.."
//                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ this one
```

**You are trying to reference whole array again as your reference to the current item.**

It can be read as `value as label for collection`. Now, **you should't have the whole array itself as `label` for each item**, should you?

Instead, you can have it like this for the array of strings,

```
ng-options="group as group for group in widget.GroupNameSearch..
```

Comment: Thanks your answer pointed me in the right direction. Another problem was that the array was of the type string. so i had to recreate the array. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @RodneyWormsbecher glad it helped a little :)

Answer (score 0):

To continue what tanmay said, make sure your ng-options are like this. 
More about that here:
[ng-options with simple array init](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18202106/ng-options-with-simple-array-init)

```
<div ng-controller="Ctrl">
      <select class="form-control" ng-model="widget.selectedGroupName.groupName" id="widgetselectedGroupName" ng-options="a as a for a in groups">
```

https://jsfiddle.net/brhardwick/4eatv28b/1/